# Knockout autocomplete implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, autocomplete

I'm now implementing my own simple autocomplete for items in input. Everything works quite well, 500ms after stopping input script does AJAX call and receives suggestions from the backend. I also show them below input in select.

The problem is that I have no idea on how to control popup's visibility. When I hide it upon input's blur, I'm not even able to click it, because input loses focus and popup is immediately being hidden. What is even more problematic is the fact, that popup is displayed inside Knockout's foreach/template combo, so there are multiple inputs controlled by multiple viewmodels. This makes using jQuery to track clicks outside the input+popup area even harder.

Pieces of code:

HTML (with an attempt to track div's focus, unsuccessful):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <div class="autocomplete-container" tabindex="0" data-bind="hasFocus: nameFocused">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" data-bind="textInput: name, event: { change: changed }">
        <select class="autocomplete" size="5" data-bind="visible: showSuggestions, options: ingredientSuggestions, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedSuggestion"></select>
    </div>                    
    <span class="label label-danger" data-bind="validationMessage: name"></span>
</div>
```

Relevant JS, part of item's viewmodel:

```
var autocompleteTimer = null;
var ingredientSuggestions = ko.observableArray();
var selectedSuggestion = ko.observable();
var nameFocused = ko.observable();
var suggestionsAvailable = ko.observable(false);
var showSuggestions = ko.computed(() => nameFocused() && suggestionsAvailable());

(...)

var suggestionsReceived = function(suggestions) {

    var newSuggestions = new IngredientSuggestions(suggestions);
    ingredientSuggestions(newSuggestions.suggestions);

    suggestionsAvailable(ingredientSuggestions().length > 0);
};

var requestSuggestions = function () {

    autocompleteTimer = null;

    recipeService.getIngredientSuggestions(name(), suggestionsReceived, null);
};

var nameChanged = function (newValue) {

    if (autocompleteTimer != null) {
        clearTimeout(autocompleteTimer);
    }

    autocompleteTimer = setTimeout(requestSuggestions, 500);
};
```

I tried to keep popup visible when input *or* popup has focus. But still, when I try to click the popup, input loses focus "faster", popup hides and thus receives no click and no focus.

How should I approach hiding suggestion popup?

Comment: I would add a click event listener to body, and on click hide all suggestions. Then check if the click was on an autocomplete input or suggestions container and show related suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to combine three values in your `showSuggestions`:

1. Are there any suggestions
2. Is the search field in focus
3. *Is the suggestion select box in focus*

When switching focus, there will be a brief moment in which *nothing* is in focus, hiding the suggestion box and disallowing it to have focus. That's why you probably need a small timeout in the visibility computed.

Here's a working example that shows the behavior:

```js
const data = getData();

const query = ko.observable("");
const suggestions = ko.pureComputed(
  () => query().length
    ? data.filter(countryMatch(query().toUpperCase()))
    : []
);
  

const queryFocus = ko.observable(false)
const selectFocus = ko.observable(false);


const suggestionsAvailable = ko.pureComputed(
  () => !!suggestions().length
);

// The relevant part:
const showSuggestions = ko.pureComputed(
  () => suggestionsAvailable() && 
        (queryFocus() || selectFocus())
).extend({ deferred: true, rateLimit: 100 });


ko.applyBindings({ query, queryFocus, selectFocus, suggestions })


function countryMatch(q) {
  return c => [c.name, c.code]
    .join(" ")
    .toUpperCase()
    .includes(q);
};

function getData() { 
  return [{"name":"Afghanistan","code":"AF"},{"name":"Argentina","code":"AR"},{"name":"Belarus","code":"BY"},{"name":"Brazil","code":"BR"},{"name":"Cayman Islands","code":"KY"},{"name":"Congo, The Democratic Republic of the","code":"CD"},{"name":"Dominica","code":"DM"},{"name":"Faroe Islands","code":"FO"},{"name":"Germany","code":"DE"},{"name":"Guinea","code":"GN"},{"name":"India","code":"IN"},{"name":"Jersey","code":"JE"},{"name":"Latvia","code":"LV"},{"name":"Madagascar","code":"MG"},{"name":"Mayotte","code":"YT"},{"name":"Namibia","code":"NA"},{"name":"Niue","code":"NU"},{"name":"Paraguay","code":"PY"},{"name":"Russian Federation","code":"RU"},{"name":"Saudi Arabia","code":"SA"},{"name":"South Africa","code":"ZA"},{"name":"Syrian Arab Republic","code":"SY"},{"name":"Tunisia","code":"TN"},{"name":"United States Minor Outlying Islands","code":"UM"},{"name":"Yemen","code":"YE"}];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="search" data-bind="textInput: query,
                                hasFocus: queryFocus"/>
<select size="5" data-bind="options: suggestions,
                            optionsText: 'name',
                            hasFocus: selectFocus,
                            visible: showSuggestions">
```